# Software launched with os.system or subprocess.Popopen closes as python shuts down

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am trying to launch an android emulator from Python. I have tried the following code:

```
os.system('C:\\Nox\\bin\\Nox.exe -clone:Nox')
subprocess.Popopen('C:\\Nox\\bin\\Nox.exe -clone:Nox')
```

The emulator launched by either code closes as soon as python code is terminated. However, when I run the code (`'C:\\Nox\\bin\\Nox.exe -clone:Nox'`) in Win10 terminal, the emulator doesn't close when the terminal is closed.

How can I keep the emulator running when python code terminates? I do not want to keep python code running.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a Windows machine to try this on, but in Ubuntu the following did it for me:

```
    import subprocess

    subprocess.Popen('<your command string>', shell=True)
```

So in your case:

```
    import subprocess

    subprocess.Popen('C:\\Nox\\bin\\Nox.exe -clone:Nox', shell=True)
```

Note there is a parameter creationFlags with values that seem of interest (https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#windows-constants), however hopefully shell=True will suffice.

**Do note** the strong warnings in the documentation around opening a process with shell=True where the process being run depends upon some user input!

Comment: `shell=True` doesn't work, though I upvoted you because it is a good quality answer. Thank you. It turns out my code has no problem but there is an issue with the Python debugger I am using in Visual Studio Code. Running my code outside the debugger works as expected, that is the emulator doesn't close when code terminates. So I just have to live with that I guess.

Comment: Just a comment on `shell=True`, according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments), if passing a single string with additional arguments, `shell=True` is a must. However, my code runs without the flag. Any idea?